# Tinymce multiple classes for image

Tags: javascript, image, tinymce, tinymce-4

Can you tell me please if is possible to set multiple classes to image in Tinymce? Now I have something like this in Tinymce init function:

```
image_class_list: [
    { title: 'None', value: ''},
    { title: 'Left', value: 'fL'},
    { title: 'Right', value: 'fR'},
    { title: 'Gallery', value: 'gallery'}
],
```

which allows me to choose one class from this list in image dialog. I would like to set more than one. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use multiple classes like this:

```
image_class_list: [
        {title: 'None', value: ''},
        {title: 'Dog', value: 'dog'},
        {title: 'Cat', value: 'cat'},
        {title: 'DogCat', value: 'cat dog'}
],
```

Note the last example that uses multiple values separated by spaces.

Comment: I know about this possibility, but this is not what I mean. I mean multiselect.

Comment: You would have to copy the image plugin and modify how it works to make a change at that level.  The plugin uses the windowManager (as do all native TinyMCE dialogs) and the code uses a listbox field type.  Unfortunately the native TinyMCE dialogs don't provide a multi select list capability so I can't point you to any example of doing that.